# Base resistor for BJT Transistor

Tags: arduino, transistors, resistors, switches, bjt

I'd like to use [PBSS4350SS](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1624748.pdf) transistors for driving multiple low power solenoids, but looking at the datasheet I can't figure out what value the base resistor (R1) should be?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe5i8k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you do a site search for "Base Resistor" you can see this question has been asked a lot of times before. Here's a link to a good answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/125246/103993

Answer (score 4):

Work out the current through L1, roughly 12V divided by its resistance.

Divide this by the minimum transistor gain from the data sheet, this gives you a minimum value for the base current.

The voltage across R1 is 3.3V-transistor VBE or about 2.6V.

Divide this by the base current to give you the maximum value of R1, in practice you need lower this by about 10% to ensure the transistor is driven into saturation.